# Как заменить массив внутри объекта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть объект в состоянии:

```
const [ops, setOps] = useState({
    names: ["МТС", "Билайн", "Мегафон"],
    links: ["/mts.img", "/beeline.img", "/megafon.img"]
});
```

Мне нужно в нем заменить массив в names на другой. Как это сделать?

Comment: setOps({...ops, names: [1,2,3]}), где [1,2,3] - любой новый массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменить массив:

```
setOps({
  ...ops,
  names: ['new names']
})
```

Добавить элемент в массив:

```
setOps({
  ...ops,
  names: [...ops.names, 'New one']
})
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает, ответ смогу принять через 10 минут только.

Comment: А не подскажете еще, как добавлять элементы в массив? Такое выражение не прокатывает: setOps({...ops, [...names, name]});

Comment: Еще раз благодарю